# How to set dynamically valueOptions in ZF2 form

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

I am trying to set the values of title in my form dynamically. My code for the title field:

```
 $title->setValueOptions(array(
        "mr" => $trans->get("Reservation_passenger_type_mr"),
        "mrs" => $trans->get("Reservation_passenger_type_mrs"),
        "chld" => $trans->get("Reservation_passenger_type_child"),
    ));
```

Then I use the following code to display it x number of times depending on the numberOfPassengers which consists of adults and children

```
$collection = new Collection('persons');        
$collection->setCount($this->numberOfPassengers); 
$this->add($collection);
```

If the number of Passangers includes some children I want to display the chld title first as a default:

```
$title->setValueOptions(array(
    "chld" => $trans->get("Reservation_passenger_type_child"),
    "mr" => $trans->get("Reservation_passenger_type_mr"),
    "mrs" => $trans->get("Reservation_passenger_type_mrs"),        
));
```

Any idea how it can be done in the code?

Comment: I can't see why can't you use an `if` statement, can you post more infos/code ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change the order of the value options, simply set the selected value of the field as follows :

```
if (/* collection includes some children */) {
    $title->setValue('chld');
}
```